# Not able to join 3 tables properly

Tags: sql, sql-query-store

I'm not able to join the following 3 tables properly :

```
AUTHORS (au_id, au_lname, au_fname, phone, address, city, state, country, postalcode)

TITLES (title_id, title, type, pub_id, price, advance, total_sales, notes, pubdate, contract)

TITLEAUTHOR (au_id, title_id, au_ord, royaltyper)
```

My question is who are the authors of the books of type 'business' or 'psychology' which are priced between $15 and $25? Give the heading as “Author Name” (concatenate first and last name).

Comment: Use the TITLEAUTHOR table to join the other two tables using the id columns.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to join them?

Comment: If you include you own attempt to solve the question, you will receive answers that will help you to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, ' ', a.au_lname)
FROM AUTHORS a
JOIN TITLEAUTHOR ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
JOIN TITLES t       ON ta.title_id = t.title_id
WHERE t.type IN ('business', 'psychology')
    AND t.price BETWEEN 15 AND 25
```

Comment: The table TITLES doesn't have a column au_id. You have to JOIN with the table TITLEAUTHOR first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, a.au_lname) as [Author Name]
FROM AUTHORS a

INNER JOIN TITLEAUTHOR ta 
                ON ta.au_id = a.au_id
 INNER JOIN TITLES ti 
                ON ti.title_id = ta.title_id
WHERE ti.type = 'business' or  ti.type =  'psychology'
    and ti.price BETWEEN 15 and 25
```